# SSL cetificate differ from root user to another

Tags: php, email, ssl

I'm new about SSL subject.

I'm trying to send emails though my website (built with Laravel 4.2) and it gives me this error:

**stream_socket_enable_crypto(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed**

If I run this command in the server with root user:

> openssl s_client -connect mail.mywebsite.com -starttls smtp

It shows me the correct certificate and gives me this answer at the end:

**Verify return code: 0 (ok)**

But if I run this command with another user:

> su myuser
>
> openssl s_client -connect mail.mywebsite.com -starttls smtp

It shows a different certificate and it gives me this answer at the end:

**Verify return code: 18 (self signed certificate)**

If I run top -c I see my php processes run with myuser and php-cgi, and since myuser has the wrong certificate, emails are not send.

Can anybody help me?

Comment: Please check that both `openssl` are the same, i.e. same path. Also check the OPENSSLDIR setting in `openssl version -V` and verify, that they both point to the same path and that the non-privileged user has the correct permissions to read the files in OPENSSLDIR/certs.

Answer (score 0):

While I was checking Steffen Ullrich response about openssl path, I found out that I needed to install through WHM the SSL certificate for my non-privileged user, and that was it.

Thanks.